# Debian: Why is the base system installation taking so long?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am installing Debian 10 on a 32GB USB for the sake of trying it. It's been 2 hours, yet it is just in half of the progress.

I did all the normal installation progress, I used Etcher for making the USB bootable (another support USB). I did the partition as the installer did, except for the swap area (which was 17GB!), which I changed to 2GB.

Is it normal or is it an error? Why and how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a USB 2.0 or 3.0, or even a 3.1 device and what is the port? Also is this a netinstall image?

Comment: It is a 3.0 device; yes, it is a netintall image, amd64

Comment: So USB 3.0 has a maximum theoretical bandwidth of 625 MB/s and it has to be both a USB 3.0 port and a 3.0 device to even think about getting close to that. And you have to split that in half for read/write and since you are using 2 drives at the same time (1 as the installer and 1 as the install target) *and* this is a netinstall meaning that your internet speed can easily be the biggest bottleneck.  I have had a Debian netinstall take over half an hour to complete on an M.2 NVMe SSD because the network speeds were barely 3 Mbps. Switch to a different tty to see the installation progress too.

Comment: Another aspect is that the installation regularly flushes writes to disk, which can cause it to take forever on USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some computers have a mix of USB2 and USB3 ports, ensure you use the one with the blue centre for USB3 and faster transmission of data. Likewise you should consider the type of USB thumbdrive.
However, from my experience a 2 hour install is orders of magnitude longer than I'd expect for a base linux installation, I suspect the device is broken or the copy was interrupted before completion, try recopying the install image.

Comment: I will try recopying. Will the OS be slow on a USB? I didn't use the "fast" USB port because I didn't know .

Comment: I've used linux installed on USB storage for many years for a variety of purposes, some devices such as Rasperry PI's use SD cards for their main storage, applications are slower to start than from an internal HDD/SSD but certainly useable.

Comment: Ok, I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Debian installer is basically a `.deb` package installer, which installs the whole system package-by-package. It writes data with force syncronization of each written file to disk (`fsync()` call). This is a default feature of `apt`/`dpkg`, to ensure system state and consistency in case of sudden power loss during package manipulation.

However this feature makes ISO installer insanely slower than it should be, and it's pointless for the OS installation stage.

Use https://bitbucket.org/ValdikSS/debian-iso-fastinstall/ to patch your ISO and install the OS from the patched file. It decreases install time for me from 1 hour 44 minutes 20 seconds down to 10 minutes 37 seconds.

The bug report is here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=700633